# Is it feasible to translate table definitions used by Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are going to use Spring-Batch in a project that needs to read, convert and write big ammounts of data. So far, everything is fine.

But there is a non-functional requirement that says we can't create DB objects using english words, so the original schema used by Spring Data will not be aproved by client's DBA, unless we translate it.

In docs, I don't see any way to configure or extend the API to achieve this objective, so it seems that we'll have to customize source code to make it work with the equivalent, translated, model. Is that a correct/feasible assumption, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an unusual requirement.  However, in order to completely rename the tables and columns in the batch schema, you'll need to re-implement the JDBC based repository DAOs to use your own SQL.

Comment: Well, I do agree on the unusual requirement part! Yet, we are currently trying to explain this situation to our client, in order to try to avoid such re-implementation (but probably to no avail). Thanks for your confirmation, it's going to be very helpful.